# Creating a year picker with angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to buil a simple year picker using angular 7, using material forms.

I was reading the documentation and found the following page:

https://v7.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

However the example on the page for what I want is not working.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ayaeglgjpqr?file=app%2Fdatepicker-views-selection-example.ts

When I run the example I get the following error:

"normalizedYear.year is not a function"

I have tried the code on my local enviroment and get the same problem. Is this some issue with angular 7 and momentjs?